# Formula for combinatorial series sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

As a part of one computer algorithm, I want to find sum for $$n+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2!} + \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3!}+....+ \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+r-1)}{r!} $$. I looked at $$\frac1{(1-x)^n}$$. But it is infinite series. Is there some formula? Please help.

Comment: Your series is $\sum_{k=1}^r\binom{n-1+k}k$.

Comment: $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n+r-1}r=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n+r-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n}n$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{2!(n+1-2)!} = {n+1 \choose 2}$$